# How to perform like operation over jsonb array column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jsonb, criteriabuilder

The column type is jsonb and the data is stored as array. I want to perform like operation on each and every member of this array.

Sample data:
`["AWS.RDS.Instance.instance-id-dee4343", "AWS.RDS.Instance.instance-id-12132", "AWS.ELBv2.instance-id-23232"]`

If input param is "AWS.RDS" then the first 2 members should be returned as the result.

I am trying to formulate a JPA criteriabuilder based query for this task but not able to form SQL statement is the first hurdle.